# Entity Framework: Querying Polymorphic Navigation Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, linq-to-entities

I have this base class named `Favorite`:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Favorite : Entity
{
    public DateTime WhenCreated { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

And 2 concrete classes, `FavoriteQuestion` and `FavoriteArticle`:

```
public class FavoriteQuestion : Favorite
{
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}

public class FavoriteArticle : Favorite
{
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
}
```

This create the following table schema:

```
Id, WhenCreated, Comments, Question_Id, Article_Id, Discriminator
```

Now, i have this service method that is handling the Favorite process and needs to check whether there already is an existing `T` (`FavoriteQuestion` / `FavoriteArticle`) with the passed `itemId`.

```
public int Favorite<T>(int itemId) where T : Favorite
{
     var isExists = db.Set<T>().Any(x => x. ???)
}
```

**How can I write a polymorphic LINQ query to determine whether a record exists for the given `T` and it's `itemId`?**

(Please note that both `Question` and `Article` inherit directly from `Entity` and do not share any other base class)

**Update:**

Here are the exposed relevant `DbSets`:

```
public IDbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
public IDbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
public IDbSet<Favorite> Favorites { get; set; }
```

Comment: And what is Entity?  Code-first entities don't usually derive from Entity framework entity classes, so i'm assuming this is a class of yours?

Comment: I added the relevant code to the question.

Comment: How is your DbContext defined?  What DbSets do you have in it?

Comment: Nothing unusual about the `DbContext`. I added the relevant code to the question.

Comment: There are many ways to define your DbContext, so claiming there's "nothing unusual" is missing the point.  For example, I see you aren't including FavoriteQuestion or FavoriteArticle in your DbSet, so EF won't know anything about these...

Comment: I don't include those concrete types because i wish to access them in a polymorphic way (using `Favorites`), just like `Questions` and `Articles` which are polymorphic data-sets as well.

Comment: Also, Entity Framework requires all entities to have parameterless constructors, so FavoriteArticle and FavoriteQuestion won't work that way anyways.

Comment: I do have parameter-less constructor, just omitted for brevity.

Comment: Omitting for brevity ends up wasting more time because we end up spending time discussing something that wouldn't otherwise need to be discussed.  If you were omitting for brevity, then you wouldn't even include the pararmetrized constructor, because it's useless to this question.

Comment: My question didn't mention anything about exception or parameter-less ctor problems, all i wanted to know is there a way to query on data that is defined in child classes (`QuestionFavorite` / `ArticleFavorite`) when the exposed type is of the base class (`Favorite`).

Comment: The problem was not anything to do with the base type.. it was that the item you need to query was named differently in your derived classes...  In other words, you were not using your item polymorphically, even though they had a common base class, they had two separate instance variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that this is *NOT* polymorphic.

I think what you need here is an Item class, derived from Entity which Question and Article derive from.

```
public class Item : Entity {...}

public class Article : Item {...}
public class Question : Item {...}
```

Then you can add Item to Favorite

```
public abstract class Favorite : Entity
{
    ...
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
public int Favorite<T>(int itemId) where T : Favorite
{
    var isExists = db.Set<T>().Any(x => x.Item.Id == itemId)
    ...
}
```

Of course, this would allow a Question to be added to a FavoriteArticle... but EF doesn't deal wit generics so you have some limitations here and you would end up having to enforce the constraint in code.

Alternatively, you could make the type of Item to be Entity, but then it broadens the types that could be used to include FavoriteQuestion and FavoriteArticle.  But it would get rid of the extra type that is used just for narrowing the type.

EDIT:

Include Entity in your DbContext, or you will get errors.

```
public IDbSet<Entity> Entities {get; set;}
public IDbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
public IDbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
public IDbSet<Favorite> Favorites { get; set; }
```

Comment: `itemId` is the `Question/Article` id, not `Favorite.Id`. `T` can be either `QuestionFavorite` or `ArticleFavorite`.

Comment: You don't have any id in your code besides the Entity Id, which is inherited by Favorite, and thus inherited by Question and Article.  Id is your primary key, and what you use to identify your rows, be they questions or articles.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, the query you're suggesting checks for `Favorite.Id` while i'm interested in `FavoriteQuestion.Id` or `FavoriteArticle.Id` (depends on the `T`).

Comment: @haim770 - You don't have any ID defined in your code for question of article.  Unless you're not showing us all the code.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, `x => x.Question.Id` or `x => x.Article.Id`. I just need a way to express it in a polymorphic way (depends on the `T`).

Comment: @haim770 - Ahh, I understand now, I misunderstood and thought you mean FavoriteQuestion when you meant the Question that's in the FavoriteQuestion.

Comment: I can't change the inheritance tree of `Article` and `Question` now. I tried with `public virtual Entity Item { get; set; }` instead but got a whole bunch of runtime errors. I'll paste them here in a moment.

Comment: @haim770 - include Entities in your DbContext.  That should get rid of them.

Comment: There are still lots of errors: `An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when: PK is NOT in 'Entities' EntitySet OR Entity is a [any entity derives from Entity]`.

Comment: @haim770 - if you add the Entities to your DbContext that will go away.  I am doing just that, and it works just fine using your examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
x => 
(x as FavoriteQuestion).Question.Id == itemId 
|| 
(x as FavoriteArticle).Article.Id == itemId
```

Should work or not?